# Cascading Driven Self-Hosted Version Server Error

Tags: java, hadoop, connection, cascading

I am using a Driven Self-Hosted version in a Cloudera-5 (CDH-5) VM.

I was able to install the Driven server successfully and able to open the server in the URL localhost.localdomain:8080.

I have provided the below values in the file cascading-service.properties

```
cascading.management.document.service.apikey=API_KEY from Driven Server
cascading.management.service.jar=/usr/lib/cascading-2.5.5/driven-plugin-1.0.1-eap-68-io.jar
cascading.management.document.service.hosts=localhost.localdomain
```

But I am facing the following error when executing Cascading Jobs and the jobs are not getting displayed in the Driven Server. But the Cascading job finishes successfully.

I tried giving the value localhost,localhost.localdomain,127.0.0.1 and also the IP of the VM, but I was facing the same error everytime.

Am I missing something here? Please assist to solve this issue.

```
14/07/07 05:55:38 WARN http.FailoverHosts: localhost.localdomain is malformed URL and will not be used as a Driven host.
14/07/07 05:55:38 ERROR rest.DrivenDocumentService: could not start service so it will be disabled.
driven.DrivenException: driven.DrivenException: no valid driven hosts provided
at driven.management.rest.DrivenDocumentService.doStartService(DrivenDocumentService.java:151)
at driven.management.rest.DrivenDocumentService.startService(DrivenDocumentService.java:120)
at cascading.management.state.BaseState.safelyStartService(BaseState.java:84)
at cascading.management.state.BaseState.startService(BaseState.java:76)
at cascading.stats.CascadingStats.prepare(CascadingStats.java:114)
at cascading.flow.BaseFlow.createPrepareFlowStats(BaseFlow.java:312)
at cascading.flow.BaseFlow.initialize(BaseFlow.java:197)
at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopPlanner.buildFlow(HadoopPlanner.java:280)
at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopPlanner.buildFlow(HadoopPlanner.java:80)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:459)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:450)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:426)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:275)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:220)
at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:202)
at first.Finalcount.main(Finalcount.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: driven.DrivenException: no valid driven hosts provided
at driven.management.http.FailoverHosts.<init>(FailoverHosts.java:53)
at driven.management.rest.DrivenDocumentService.getUploadClient(DrivenDocumentService.java:205)
at driven.management.rest.DrivenDocumentService.doStartService(DrivenDocumentService.java:136)
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tried this one:

```
cascading.management.document.service.hosts=http://localhost:8080
```

Should work.